# Combine multiple fields in Data Studio into a single Field from same source

Tags: looker-studio

Is it possible to combine fields in Data Studio into a single data field?

Example:

Data Source - "ExampleSheet"

Available Fields - "Date", "Pet", "Food", "Movies"

Formula I need would take "Pet" and "Food" and turn them into "All the things"

But still be able to have the data align to add "Date" next to the new field.

So, the resulting table would look like this:

Date ||  Pet

Date || Food

Date || Pet

Date || Food

Date || Pet

Date ||  Pet

I know it's a long shot, but I want the data to be able to filter without breaking the source into another data source and concat the data into columns breaks the ability to align the data

I tried blended data, but it doesn't like the values being from the same source

You don't have to work it all out for me, just help point me in the right area if it is possible. Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the new fields by using [CONCAT](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7583443?hl=en).

Example: `Pet Date` would be `CONTACT(Pet, " ", Date)`.

View [About calculated fields](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en&ref_topic=7570421) to learn more about Calculated Fields in Data Studio.

Comment: Thanks Minhaz! I appreciate the follow up. Unfortunately, I am looking for the ability to join two fields in the same column of a table, with the first row remaining as the date. I have tried a few versions, but it looks like I am just going to have to query the source data and not have the data align with the rest of the Data Studio.